# Size of an abelian permutation group with generators of order 2

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $g_1, \ldots, g_k$ be distinct permutations on a set $\Omega$. Suppose that $G = \langle g_1, \ldots, g_k \rangle$ is an abelian permutation group with only elements of order at most 2. Is it possible that $|G| = k$? If not, can $|G|$ be polynomial in $k$?

Comment: What is $\Omega$? 

Comment: It's the set of points on which G is acting. I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Why not $k=n$, all the distinct elements of $G$? If you mean that no proper subset of $\langle g_1 \cdots g_k$ generates $G$ then $n = 2^k$ no? If you mean something else what? 

Comment: You are right, it didn't make much sense. I've uptaded the question.

Comment: Assuming $k$ is fixed, the possibilities for $|G|$ are all the powers of 2 in the range `$k\leq |G|\leq 2^k$`.  (This might or might not answer the question, depending on what the question actually is.)

Comment: I think http://math.stackexchange.com is a better home for your question.